# Does casting the Glyph of Warding spell from a spell scroll take 1 action or 1 hour?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, action-economy, traps

Does casting the *glyph of warding* spell from a spell scroll take 1 action or 1 hour?

Say a wizard has a scroll of *glyph of warding* (GOW). Would they be able to, at time of casting - assuming you can now cast it in one action, rather than one hour - store a spell in it, if they had remaining spell slots and a spell prepared that is able to be put in GOW?

Comment: The question in the body seems to not quite match the title... The body assumes that the answer to the title question is "yes", and then seems to state a question whose answer seems "yes" if the assumption is true... (I see the title was changed to what it was by NautArch before my slight edit.)

Comment: Are these Related to the intent of this question, if not the wording?   
[Is there a way to accelerate or pre-cast spells with long casting times?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/167816/is-there-a-way-to-accelerate-or-pre-cast-spells-with-long-casting-times)   
 \ [Does a Spell Gem Reduce the Casting Time of Any Imbued Spell to a Single Action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/177865/does-a-spell-gem-reduce-the-casting-time-of-any-imbued-spell-to-a-single-action)

Answer (score 6):

## A Spell Scroll has the same cast time as the original spell

This is made clear, after the [2015 DMG errata](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/DMG_Errata.pdf), in the description for a Spell Scroll:

> A spell scroll bears the words of a single spell, written as a mystical cipher. If the spell is on your class's spell list, you can read the scroll and cast its spell without having to provide any of the spell's components. Otherwise, the scroll is unintelligible. **Casting the spell by reading the scroll requires the spell's normal casting time.** Once the spell is cast, the words on the scroll fade, and it crumbles to dust. If the casting is interrupted, the scroll is not lost.
>
> [...]
>
> —**Spell Scroll**, Dungeon Master's Guide, pg. 200

So for *Glyph of Warding*, a spell that has a cast time of one hour, it would take an hour to cast a *Scroll of Glyph of Warding*.

Comment: Sets up for battles to break a reader's concentration on an epic Spell Scroll recitation... If @Carl Bozeman wants to ready a spell with a long casting time, for use at a single action, perhaps acquiring Spell Gems is a more suitable answer than Spell Scrolls?